# JDBS string for connecting to a PDB database table?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a Oracle container DB SID orcl and pluggabel DB named pdb1. pdb1 has a table named customers. I am able to make the connection to database but I want to connect to a database table.

Below is the jdbc url string I am able to construct:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/pdb1
```

I am using this string in a scripted sql connector. What parameter has to be included in this url string to connect to the table?

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect to a table but to a database's schema.
The database is specified by the connection string and the schema by the user's name.